# Spring Data upsert by equals

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I want to update/insert an entity, depending not on primary key but on equals:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Builder
class Alert {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "field1")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String field1;

    @Column(name = "field2")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String field2;

    @Column(name = "field3")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String field3;

    @Column(name = "last_occurrence")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastOccurrence;
}

Alert alert = Alert.builder().field1("foo").field2("bar").lastOccurence(new Date()).build();
```

If equals alert exists (e.g., with field1="foo", field2="bar" and field3=null), I want to update its lastOccurence, else insert the new alert.

(Of course, I could use a nasty derived query method like findByField1AndField2AndField3...)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using spring, you can take advantage of `Example`. Assume you have an `AlertReporitory` that implements `JpaRepository`, then you can do the following:

```
Alert alert = Alert.builder().field1("foo").field2("bar").lastOccurence(new Date()).build();
Optional<Alert> dbAlert = alertRepository.findOne(Example.of(alert));
if (dbAlert.isPresent()) {
    // update
} else {
    // insert
}
```

Comment: I used a combination of this with ExampleMatcher.withIgnorePaths and withIncludeNullValues and it solved my problem.